# ODBC Excel SQL Condition

Tags: sql, excel, odbc, case, clr

I need to build a SQL query to read an Excel file, through ODBC with the **`Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)`**.

That query needs a conditional statement in the `SELECT` that expresses "if the column `A` from the page `TA` has the value `x`, then `R1`, else `R2`", `R1` and `R2` being values of the same type (`0` and `1` or `'ABC'` and `'DEF'`).

With `CASE` it would normally give

```
SELECT CASE A WHEN x THEN R1 ELSE R2 END AS RA FROM TA;
```

or

```
SELECT CASE WHEN A = x THEN R1 ELSE R2 END AS RA FROM TA;
```

This creates an error saying there's a missing operator.

Looking around I've read that Access (because no one gives a darn about Excel) does not have the `CASE` statement.

I've then tried the `IIF` statement,

```
SELECT IIF (A = x, R1, R2) AS RA FROM TA;
```

which doesn't work, with an error telling tales about either missing operators or missing ODBC fields depending on how I expressed the condition (I use a vanilla `CRecordset` object, it fails on the `Open` call, and I don't do `DoFieldExchange` nowhere),

then I tried the `SWITCH` statement

```
SELECT SWITCH (A = x, R1, true, R2) AS RA FROM TA;
```

which failed too ("Too few arguments. 1 expected."), then I tried the `CHOOSE` statement

```
SELECT CHOOSE (1*(A = x), R1, R2) AS RA FROM TA;
```

which, surprisingly, doesn't work, with the same results.

I also tried all these queries with `RA = ...` instead of `... AS RA`, to no avail.

How do I properly express a condition in a SQL query aimed at an Excel file through ODBC?

Edit: I know presuming ignorance is the norm in there, so let me be clear, `[A]` IS a column in `TA`, `R1` and `R2` just express the desired values, in my case those are literal values (`72` and `70` respectively). My queries are also far larger, requesting multiple columns from `joins` with `wheres` and an `order by`, and all my queries worked well until now, with simple `CRecordset` objects that I'd call `GetFieldValue` from. Any query I added a conditional statement to started to fail. I've extensively debugged my work and the queries are correctly formatted as far as I can tell (no missing parentheses or such). I also have no Actual Knowledge that these statements are unsupported; a correction on my syntax that would work is welcome.

I CANNOT simply get `TA.A` then handle its value in code and I CANNOT use an API or a different driver to access the data.

Edit2:
@Parfait:

```
CDatabase *here_db = new CDatabase () ;
here_db->OpenEx ("Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)};DBQ=C:\\ExcelFile.xls") ;
CRecordset *here_rs = new CRecordset (here_db) ;
here_rs->Open (CRecordset::snapshot, "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [TableA$]", CRecordset::readOnly) ;
//This works, btw.
int rowCount ;
CDBVariant v ;
here_rs->GetFieldValue ((short) 0, v, SQL_C_SLONG) ;
rowCount = v.m_lVal ;
here_rs->Close () ;
here_rs->Open (CRecordset::snapshot, CString (
    "SELECT"
    " CASE A"
    "   WHEN 'test' THEN 72"
    "   ELSE 70"
    " END AS RA"
    " FROM [TableA$]"
    ""), CRecordset::readOnly) ;
short i ;
int colCount ;
colCount = here_rs->GetODBCFieldCount () ;
CString h ("") ;
while (!here_rs->IsEOF ())
{
    for (i = 0; i < c; i++)
    {
        here_rs->GetFieldValue (i, h) ;
    }
    here_rs->MoveNext () ;
}
here_rs->Close () ;
delete here_rs ;
here_db->Close () ;
delete here_db ;
return TRUE ;
```

Edit3: This is CPP/Cli.

The Jet and Ace data providers work with OLEDB objects, I don't know that you can use them with CDatabase/CRecordset.

I went back to this after the week-end, rebuild my query, checked all the table names, file paths, column names etc, tried an IFF, and it worked. With the Microsoft Excel Driver and all. I'm assuming I made a syntax error somewhere but I can't for the life of me figure what it was. Anyways here is the query that ended working:

```
if (!here_rs->Open (CRecordset::snapshot,
    "SELECT"
    "   `A`,"
    "   IIF(`A` = x, 72, 70) AS RA"
    " FROM `TableA$`"
    "", CRecordset::readOnly))
{
    __debugbreak () ;
}
```

Since Parfait's answer is correct, I'll mark it as such. I'll still welcome an explanation as to what happened, if anyone has it.

Comment: What language is this? Please tag it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Querying Excel workbooks in Windows environments would involve the JET/ACE SQL engine (Windows .dll files) which is the very same engine used in MS Access. Since this SQL dialect  does not support ANSI's `CASE` statement, the best equivalent would be the [`IIF` function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/iif-function-32436ecf-c629-48a3-9900-647539c764e3). From your statement:

> [A] IS a column in TA, R1 and R2 just express the desired values

Then, your `IIF` expression must treat the test and desired values as quoted literals if using alphanumerics. Otherwise the engine assumes they are fields in table. Do note: you *can* use actual columns in `IIF`. Also, use a table alias for *TA* designation.

```
SELECT IIF(TA.A = 'test', 'R1', 'R2') AS RA 
FROM [TableA$] AS TA
```

And for number values as used in attempted code, do not quote them. In both expressions you are implicitly assigning a data type (string and integer respectively) while explicitly assigning values to new calculated column, *RA*:

```
SELECT IIF(TA.A = 'test', 72, 70) AS RA 
FROM [TableA$] AS TA
```